# PHP-Update a column with the minimum value of multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL Table with multiple columns:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | min_all_col |
 25  |  27  |  35  |  21  |  37  |  34  |             |
```

I need to know how I can update the column (min_all_cols), with the minimum value
of all 6 columns e.g 21
I have tried several UPDATE statements but just seem to confuse myself.

Can anyone help me?
Regards

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you need a separate column for this, and not simply calculate it at run time? [clue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Comment: `... min_all_col = LEAST(col1,col2,col3,col4...)`

Comment: I tried the following

Comment: I tried the LEAST which seems to work, but it does not update the field, I would like it to add an entry into the min_all_cols columns

Comment: As I asked before, __why__ do you need to actually store this in the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

> **LEAST(value1,value2,...)**
>
> With two or more arguments, returns the smallest (minimum-valued)
> argument.

```sql
UPDATE tableName
SET min_all_col = LEAST(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6);
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdcc4c/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Filipe! i was looking at it far to much in depth, a simple solution to a simple problem.